# Expectation formula of an integrable random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Given $X$ is integrable. Prove that $E(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F(x)]dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0}F(x)dx$.

**My 2ND solution** Since $X$ is integrable, $E(X) = E(X^{+}) - E(X^{-}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} xdF_{X^{+}}(x) - \int_{0}^{\infty} xdF_{X^{-}}(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} [F_{X^{-}}(x) - F_{X^{+}}(x)]dx$.

Now, since $F_{X^{-}}(x) = P(-min(X,0)\leq x) = 1 - P(\min(X,0)<\ -x) = 1 - P(X<-x)$  (since for $x\in (0,\infty), P(0<-x) = 0$)

$= 1 - F_{X}(-x)$, $E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} [1 - F_{X}(-x) - F_{X^{+}}(x)] dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} 1 - F_{X}(x) - \int_{0}^{\infty} F_{X}(-x)dx$ (the last equality is because for $x\in (0,\infty), F_{X^{+}}(X) = F_{X}(x)$).

Finally, by using the change of variable $u=-x$ for the 2nd integral, with $u$ as a dummy variable, we easily get the RHS that we need (Q.E.D)

**My question:** Could someone help review the solution above to see if it's correct this time? Would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Why is it true that $X$ is either always positive or always negative?

Comment: Well, that's a good question. I guess by looking at the definition of $E(X)$ (as $X$ is integrable), we could see that either one of the term is defined on a particular interval. And then we sum all of the integrals over all of those intervals to get $E(X)$. Hmm...I should use $E[X] = E[X^{+}] - E[X^{-}]$, and so only needs to worry about the positive case, and then computing $\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_{X^{+}}(x)] - [1-F_{X^{-}}(x)]dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} F_{X^{-}}(x) - F_{X^{+}}(x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F_{X^{+}}(x)]dx - \int_{-\infty}^{0} F_{X^{-}}(x)dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tonelli's theorem we see that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^+] &= \int_\Omega X^+(\omega)\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \int_\Omega\int_0^{X^+(\omega)} \mathsf 1_{\{X^+(\omega)>t\}}(t,\omega)\,\mathsf dt\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_\Omega \mathsf 1_{\{X^+(\omega)>t\}}(t,\omega)\,\mathsf d\mathbb P(\omega)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X^+>t).\\
&= \int_0^\infty (1-F(t))\,\mathsf dt.
\end{align}

Since $X^-$ is also nonnegative, applying the same argument along with a change of variables yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^-] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X^->t)\,\mathsf dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty \mathbb P(-X^-\leqslant -t)\,\mathsf dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 \mathbb P(X\leqslant t)\,\mathsf dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^0 F(t)\,\mathsf dt.
\end{align}
It follows then that
$$\mathbb E[X] = \mathbb E[X^+] - \mathbb E[X^-] =\int_0^\infty (1-F(t))\,\mathsf dt - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(t)\,\mathsf dt.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think yours is essentially the same as mine, except you jump quite a bit from the 2nd line to the 3rd line of $E(X^{-})$?